# 'Adding Member Function to only Specialized Template of Class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization

I have a template class and I want to add a special function to a particular specialization of the template. This function only makes sense for the std::string template.

I showed how I am handling this currently...the problem is that the deleted function is still visible to all template types, and not just the Match template that I want to use it with.

**Is there a more elegant way to handle this dilemma?**

```
 template<typename T> 
 class Match {

  /*
   *Class Definition
   * 
   */

   void string_function() = delete;
 };

template<>
void Match<Std::string>::string_function(){

    //do something that only makes sense with strings
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can factor the common code in a base class template and make derived specialization with the tailored features.

```
template <typename T>
class BaseMatch { /* Common features across all specializations... */ };

template <typename T>
class Match : BaseMatch<T> { /* Generic case, no custom behavior to enforce */ };

template <>
class Match<std::string> : BaseMatch<std::string> {
    void string_function() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer. Can I know why you edited out the SFINAE solution in favor of this derived specialization solution?

Comment: @Blondie The sfinae solution cannot work because T is static for a given specialization. Thus one of the 2 `string_function` would issue a compiler error because the `enable_if_t` is not valid.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks alot. This derived specialization solution is very elegant.

Comment: what if i wanted to hide the definition of BaseMatch from the outside world?

Comment: @Blondie Common practice in template programming (since you can't hide implementation details) is to simply enclose those details in `namespace detail`.

Answer (score -1):

```
void string_function() = delete;
```

It will deallocate function from class scope, again you tring to define function. 
It's like if you deleted a gmail account and try to login saying not able to login, 
that is not possible right, may I know the reason why you want to delete than can come up with some solution.